# Not opening fragment after checking internet connection

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to open a fragment if there is no internet connection.

I am using following code:

```
 public boolean isConnected(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

            if((mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting())) return true;
            else return false;
        } else return false;
    }

    public AlertDialog.Builder buildDialog(Context c) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder.setTitle("No Internet connection.");
        builder.setMessage("You have no internet connection");


        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("HOLA PERFIL", "NO HAY INTERNET:   QUITADO EL DIALOG" );

                SinInternetFragment firstFragment = new SinInternetFragment();

                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.frame, firstFragment).commit();

            }
        });

        return builder;
    }
```

But after pressing the OK button, the dialog is dismissed but the fragment is not shown, it stays in the same fragment.

But should I changed?

Comment: You see this in your logs NO HAY INTERNET:   QUITADO EL DIALOG ?

Comment: @android_Muncher, yes, I see that line in the logs.

Comment: @Vikrant, yes, I have checked and same result.

Comment: Assuming you're not seeing any crashes or anything, it seems like only one of two things are likely. (1) calling `.add()` instead of `.replace()` is putting the fragment "behind" something else, or (2) your `SinInternetFragment` doesn't create a view. I'd be interested to see your fragment's code as well as your MainActivity layout.